# Usage of memory increasing rapidly in Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

When starting my Android wallpaper application, the application consumes slowly more and more memory. I am trying to figure out why this is happening and haven't been very successful yet.

At one time I got an information in logcat as "Low memory no more background process". At this time my app quit for a few seconds and restart it again.

Am calling two native functions repeatedly on the background to draw the wallpaper. Is this problem?

Comment: You need to show some code and/or log info for us to help more

Answer (score 2):

Please read: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

You are probably using static members and reusing widgets with old `Context` and that makes android unable to free the memory of old contexts that expired long ago.

1. Don't use static members when you can avoid it
2. Under no conditions should you set a widget to public/default static always use private
3. Use final as much as you can
4. Do more research online